# Content Script does not receive the object I send

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension and I want to send a message from a content script to a background script requesting a var that gets send back. Like this:

```
contentscript.js --> ask for var --> background.js
                                          |
contentscript.js <-- give var <------------
```

This are the files:

```
// contentscript.js

'use strict';

function canGo() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: 'go' }, function(response) {
    return response.go;
  });
}

console.log(canGo()); // undefined
```

and

```
// background.js

'use strict';

var go = false;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message == 'go') {
      sendResponse({ go: go });
    }
  }
);
```

So the problem is that the function `canGo` returns undefined. I can't find why. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.runtime.sendMessage` is asynchronous.

Your function `canGo()` will terminate right after sending the message, and the callback will be called asynchronously later. You cannot use the response immediately, you have to use it from within the callback.

```
function canGo() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: 'go' }, function(response) {
    console.log(response.go);
    if(response.go) { /* ... */ }
    else { /* ... */ }
  });
}
```